# Azure BlobClient DeleteIfExistsAsync error: 404 The specified blob does not exist

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

```
var blobClient = new BlobClient(
                this.containerOUT,
                this.containerOUTName,
                targeturlFilename);

// targeturlFilename sample: 2022/10/04/Partner/Subject/b638289b-313e-434f-9825-0f8691fcebc6/86f98707-0e50-4f0d-8ac9-84c835379dfd.dat

await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(); // right here throws 404 error      
var response = await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(targeturlFilename, rawStream);
```

i have this code above that should delete one after blob if it exists another one.
But then in `DeleteIfExistsAsync` it generates error 404 that the blob does not exist. It works perfectly when Blob exists, it deletes and uploads. But when it doesn't exist it generates the error... what would be wrong in this code?
If Blob doesn't exist, isn't it just for running code normally?

Comment: *it generates error 404 that the blob does not exist* you mean it throws an actual exception?

Comment: Hey @PeterBons! Yes, I can track this error on Application Insights in Azure. It appears as a failed dependency of Microsoft.Storage

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The Azure SDK just tries to delete the blob. If an exception occurs because it does not exists it will catch it and return `false`. The call to the blob storage returns a 404 and as such, is logged as a failed dependency. It is safe to ignore. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Blob/CloudBlob.cs#L2112

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative code to avoid this dependency error:

```
var blobClient = new BlobClient(
                    this.containerOUT,
                    this.containerOUTName,
                    targeturlFilename);

//  Just overwrite the file if it exists
var response = await blobClient.UploadAsync(rawStream, overwrite: true);
```